# laravel migration error on Mac

Tags: php, laravel, migration

hello I try to make laravel migration using `php artisan migrate` on Mac, but I still receive this error although I checked my database connection and its totally correct ...

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = mirror and table_name = migrations)

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mirror/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mirror/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=mirror", "root", "root", [])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mirror/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Check your credentials in your `.env` file. Your username and password probably aren't both `root` for your  mysql access, or it isn't allowed to connect from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: - both of them are root in my database host 
- I tried to run other project which not laravel on same credentials , its worked fine to me

Comment: Log directly into the database and run `select Host, User from mysql.user where user = 'root';`. If there is a user for localhost, try resetting the password for it. If not, you'll need to create the user.

Comment: thats work for my , thank you very much .

Comment: Delete the question it adds no value, since it was simple typographical error.